# How much slower are prepared statements for single queries?

Tags: mysql

If prepared statements are used to only insert a single row. How much slower would it be compared to not using prepared statements?

Comment: Is it not worth running a test of your own?

Comment: With what connectivity layer? JDBC, ...?

Comment: @Ardman actually testing such a micro things won't tell you anything real.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: actually, the data will tell you that the difference is statistically insignificant (which IMO is a very real and useful result, saying "don't waste time optimizing this"); but many people don't know how to check for significance.

Comment: @Piskvor only a few persons here on so able test properly. The rest will run infamous "zillion iterations of nothing" and get astonished with results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means another round trip to the database, so the difference is minimal.

The query has to be prepared regardless of whether it's done in a separate step or when the query is executed, so by making a prepared statement out of a query that only is executed once, you are only dividing the work of parsing the query into two separate steps.

Answer (score 3):

Query parsing is not the thing you should be worried about.
Learn to not to ask performance questions prematurely, but only for a reason.
And once having a reason, learn to **[profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29)** your application and be concerned in the things, really affecting performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a single row only once I suppose it does save some time not to use prepared statements. However, inserting ONE single row cannot be something you'd need to optimize.